# Why is the phasor expression of the currents and voltages of this circuit zero?

Tags: phasor

Why is the phasor expression of the currents and voltages of this circuit zero except V1 which is apparently equal to Vs.

[image]

Comment: Because the circuit is open?

Comment: @EugeneSh. i cant see the how its open from this diagram

Comment: I can't see how it is closed. Pick a line and start going along it. If you managed to get to the same point you started - congratulations, you have found a closed one. I can't.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you make a strong case lol

Comment: @EugeneSh.so why is V1 equal to Vs then? if you would be so kind as to reply

Comment: Is it? It shouldn't, as the `-` of \$V_1\$ is floating (you can see it is not connected to anything).

Comment: @EugeneSh. i dont doubt your reasoning but thats the text book answer

Comment: So it's either a bad textbook, or you are not telling us everything.

Comment: @EugeneSh. unless you want me to tell you that Z is impedance, thats everything im afraid

Comment: Ah, wait. I can see one possible way to make it work. If the wire crossing below \$Z_4\$ is actually a junction, \$V_1\$ is equal to \$V_S\$.

Comment: The - terminal of V1 is not floating. It's connected to the lower terminal of the source through Z4 and Z2. Since the currents I2 and I4 are 0, then there's no voltage drops across Z2 and Z4.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, see my comment. First though the crossing is without a connection.

Comment: The statement that V1 = Vs implies that the point below Z4 is a four way connection and not a crossover. That still leaves no path for current and no measurement points other than V1 that have paths from the + & - points to the + & - of V1.

Comment: @CharlesCowie yh thanks a lot. If you want you can write tht as an answer to the qn instead of a comment so i can mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that V1 = Vs implies that the point below Z4 is a four way connection and not a crossover. That still leaves no path for current and no measurement points other than V1 that have paths from the + & - points to the + & - of V1